# Determine local volume unit

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

How can I get user's local volume unit to determine what he preffers? Getting local distance is available by `NSLocale` but volume is kind of problem.

Comment: Whether user prefers metric units could be queried from NSLocale objectForKey: NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem or NSLocaleMeasurementSystem.

Comment: @paiv this is very good point. Volume unit can be determined by your measurement. If someone uses metric unit, his local volume unit is a liter and imperial unit is gallon.

Comment: @trick14 I am not asking about audio issue so this is not a duplicate.